# Hudson PMD & TaskScanner plugins failing

Tags: hudson

I have been setting up a windows master with a Linux slave. When running a Flex Project on the slave node and trying to launch the pmd report plugin there´s a problem with accessing the pmd file - I am sure that it exists and the path is correct:

```
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
FATAL: remote file operation failed
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed
```

I get excactly the same error when running the TaskScanner plugin. Do I need to install the plugin on the slave? In that case: how do I do that?

Comment: You might get better answers on www.superuser.com for a question like this since it isn't really programming related.

Comment: @Al Crowley - Hudson + PMD is programming related.

Comment: The Hudson users' list is very responsive.  I suggest posting there: http://n4.nabble.com/Hudson-users-f361316.html

Answer (score 1):

What version of Hudson are you using?  There was [a problem running various plugins against slave-run jobs](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4993), but [it was fixed](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5048) [in 1.337](http://hudson-ci.org/changelog.html).

Comment: Great! I was running an older version. Thanx!